# how to auto-populate field as you type in gravity forms?

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I would like to have a dropdown list that has 100 choices available but I do not want anyone to see all available options.  I would like for them to type at least the first 3 letters of the name of a choice and shows whatever starts with those letters as an option to select.  How can I accomplish this in a Gravity Forms Form?

I have simply created the form with the dropdown with all of the available choices.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider a plugin that allows for autocomplete. This way, you can preload your 100 choices: https://gravityextra.com/gravity-forms-advanced-autocomplete-field/